# unable to perform unit test in angular 8 .net core

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, testing

When I run

```
ng test command
```

Getting below error:

> [error] Error: error TS6046: Argument for '--target' option must be: 'es3', 'es5', 'es6', 'es2015', 'es2016', 'es2017', 'es2018', 'es2019', 'es2020', 'esnext'.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47139581/upgraded-to-angular-5-ts6046-and-ts5024-errors

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upgraded to Angular 5 : TS6046 and TS5024 errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47139581/upgraded-to-angular-5-ts6046-and-ts5024-errors)

Answer (score 0):

Please check `target` value of your `tsconfig.js` file (that defines compiler options)

Answer (score 0):

I have checked every option for the target in the tsconfig.js file. Still, the same error occured