# tsconfig error when start Angular 11 project

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsconfig, lit-element, angular11

I just create a project didn't do any changes. It shows error in `tsconfig.json` file. I tried to fix this by changing the `es2020` into `es2015` but it did not fix the error

```
TS6046: Argument for '--module' option must be: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es6', 'es2015', 'esnext'.
```

Here is my `tsconfig.json`

```
 {
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": "./",
  "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
  "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
  "strict": true,
  "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
  "noImplicitReturns": true,
  "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
  "sourceMap": true,
  "declaration": false,
  "downlevelIteration": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "importHelpers": true,
  "target": "es2015",
  "module": "es2020",
  "lib": [
    "es2018",
    "dom"
  ]
},
 "angularCompilerOptions": {
   "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
   "strictInjectionParameters": true,
   "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
   "strictTemplates": true
}
}
```

How can I solve this.

Comment: `"module": "es2020"` it should be `"module": "es2015"` also

Answer (score 1):

update your `tsconfig.app.json` file as well with `"module": "es2015"`

Comment: thanks for suggestion, but that did not fix the error

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that [Angular needs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47139581/upgraded-to-angular-5-ts6046-and-ts5024-errors):

```json
"module": "amd",
```

While Lit needs one of the ES module variants.